# Data not stored using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I am just learning to use prepared statements and stuck here. there is no problem with normal method. there is nothing error shown but the data is not stored in database although it displays "data entered".

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","learndb");

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed this is the error: " . $db->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO studentrecords (Name, email, Phone, school,dob,father,feereceived,due,image) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssisssiib",$first,$email,$phone,$school,$dob,$father,$feereceived,$due,$image);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt)
{
    echo"data entered";
}
```

**Update**

Data is stored but not the type required. should i specify all types in user input? Also the pattern in html form not working.

Comment: What is the type of your `$image` variable? blob or string type?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer blob type.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you wrap the entire bind_param & execute with an if condition as the statement will fail to be prepared if there is even a minor issue. In this case I would guess it could be that the types for each variable/field is wrong at some point - probably the `image` / `b` part.

You can echo the type of each using `gettype` which might help track it down:

```
echo gettype($first), gettype($email), gettype($phone),
     gettype($school), gettype($dob), gettype($father), 
     gettype($feereceived), gettype($due), gettype($image);


$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","learndb");

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed this is the error: " . $db->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO studentrecords (`Name`, `email`, `Phone`, `school`,`dob`,`father`,`feereceived`,`due`,`image`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

if($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssisssiib",$first,$email,$phone,$school,$dob,$father,$feereceived,$due,$image);
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    echo 'Failed to prepare the sql statement';
}
```

Comment: it displays all as string. but i made dob as DATE in database but it donot display as date instead of 2053-4-4 it displays 2053 only.