# Unable to store image using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

This problem is while storing image into database using prepared statements.Everything else is stored. Without prepared statement everything is fine.Here is the code:

```
$submit=isset($_POST['submit']);

if($submit)
{

$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$school=$_POST['school'];
$father=$_POST['father'];
$dob=$_POST['dob'];
$feereceived=$_POST['feereceived'];
$due=$_POST['due'];


if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); 

}

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","learndb");

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed this is the error: " . $db->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO studentrecords (Name, email, Phone, school,dob,father,feereceived,due,image) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

if($stmt)
{
    $stmt->bind_param("ssisssiib",$name,$email,$phone,$school,$dob,$father,$feereceived,$due,$image);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo"information entered.";
}
```

Comment: What you want  store image name or store whole image into database???

Comment: Please don't repost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171530/data-not-stored-using-prepared-statements - you should be editing your other question with the form you didn't include.